# How to use compute method with a map of arrays?

Tags: java

Let say there is a map

```java
HashMap<String, Double> A = new HashMap<>();
```

If I use compute() method to add 1 to its element its gonna look something like this:

```java
map.compute("Key1", (key, val) -> (val == null) ? 1 : val + 1);
```

However, what should I do in case of

```java
HashMap<String, Double[]> A = new HashMap<>();
```

if I want to add 1 to each element of the array in the same compute method? Is it possible?

Comment: Instead of `map.compute("Key1", (key, val) -> (val == null) ? 1 : val + 1);` you can simply use `map.merge("Key1", 1.0, Double::sum);` An important aspect is the initial value `1` which should be put if the key does not exist. What should happen for your `Double[]` array? You only explained what should happen when the value exist, but not when there is no mapping (create a new array? How large?). Creating a new `Double[]` array has the disadvantage that the elements are initially `null`. So rethink whether you really want `Double[]` rather than just `double[]`. Or `int[]`, as you are counting.

Answer (score 1):

The compute function takes a BiFunction, therefore you simply need to create a BiFunction to produce the results you want.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html

The example below showcases how to update the first record of your Double[].

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    HashMap<String, Double[]> mapExample = new HashMap<>();

    mapExample.put("myKey", new Double[]{0.0, 0.0});

    BiFunction<String, Double[], Double[]> mappingFunction = new BiFunction<>() {

        @Override public Double[] apply(String key, Double[] originalDoubleArrayValue) {

            originalDoubleArrayValue[0] = 10.0;
            return originalDoubleArrayValue;
        }
    };

    mapExample.compute("myKey", mappingFunction);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mapExample.get("myKey")));
}
```

---

For your required modification of all records within the array:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    HashMap<String, Double[]> mapExample = new HashMap<>();

    mapExample.put("myKey", new Double[]{0.0, 0.0});

    BiFunction<String, Double[], Double[]> mappingFunction = new BiFunction<>() {

        @Override public Double[] apply(String key, Double[] originalDoubleArrayValue) {

            if(originalDoubleArrayValue != null){

                for(int i = 0; i < originalDoubleArrayValue.length; i++){
                    originalDoubleArrayValue[i] = originalDoubleArrayValue[i]+1;
                }
                return originalDoubleArrayValue;
            }

            originalDoubleArrayValue = new Double[10];
            Arrays.fill(originalDoubleArrayValue, 1.0);

            return originalDoubleArrayValue;
        }
    };

    mapExample.compute("myKey", mappingFunction);
    mapExample.compute("keyWhichDoesNotExist", mappingFunction);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mapExample.get("myKey")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mapExample.get("keyWhichDoesNotExist")));
}
```

Console:

```
[1.0, 1.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

It has been years since I wrote a for loop :)